# Laravel Eloquent outputting array Collection instead single value

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, eloquent

I am trying to access a **SINGLE VALUE** from a row but the `dd();` is getting the whole row and showing it in the Collection array. The code:

```
$last_id = \App\Cat::limit(1)->orderBy('cat_id','desc')->get(['cat_id']);
dd($last_id);
```

So when I need the JUST `"55"` value I get :

- `"cat_id" => "55"`

Same happens with others columns, when I need JUST the "Eletronics" I get:

- `"cat_name" => "Eletronics"`

I have already tried lots of stuff like Limit, List, First and nothing happens, when I try to call something like `dd($lastId->cat_id );` it gives me a **"Undefined property"** error. SO now I am really out of options since I am using the documentation example and even that way it does not works fine. So any help would be great, thank you.

Answer (score 0):

I think you don't understand that the Model represents entire row of table. 
That means that `$last_id` in your code:

```
$last_id = \App\Cat::limit(1)->orderBy('cat_id','desc')->get(['cat_id']);
```

represents entire row of `cats` table. If you want to get `id`, you have to do this:

```
$cat = \App\Cat::first(1)->orderBy('cat_id','desc')->get();
dd($cat->id);
```

What more, if you write

```
$cat = \App\Cat::first();
```

you will get first cat from `cats` table, and then you can access every column of this row as property of `$cat` object

If Laravel says you that property `cat_id` is undefined, propably your table don't contain `cat_id` column.

Comment: I have seen the "first();" in some questions similars to that so I tried cause I do not have options, but I have to confess I never used it before, so thank you for the hint. Nevertheless I can get ONLY ONE column from lots of others tables using the "same line code" but without the "take" part. Tried your code (again, cause I really had tried it before) and it keeps saying the column does not exist. 1 - I am 100% percent sure this column exists cause I check in migrations a phpmyadmin, and if it does not exist the it would appears on the "orderBy" where I use it like parameter.

Comment: Already got it, i change the get for the "value" method.  \App\Cat::orderBy("id","desc")->value("id"); Thank you fella

Answer (score 0):

Already got it, i change the get for the "value" method.

```
\App\Cat::orderBy("id","desc")->value("id");
```